# HTML hosting with live collaboration

Tags: html, editor

I was wonderig, if it is possible to work on code simultaneously. I am currently creating stylesheet with co-worker and i need a possibilty to preview the website online. Things like git are not efficient enough. Google Drive would be awesome if it only supported syntax highlighting and previewing.

Comment: Why are things like Git not efficient enough? What is it about Google Drive that makes it awesome? In other words, please give a bit more detail about exactly what you're after; it's not clear enough from the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Koding](https://koding.com/) would provide exactly what you want.